# How to convert multi column excel table to single column with header attached

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Hi can anyone let me know if there is a good way to convert table 1 to table 2 in excel? this is just a example the actual data is in thousands of rows.

[image: Table 1]

[image: Table 2]

Thank you!

Comment: See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20541905/convert-matrix-to-3-column-table-reverse-pivot-unpivot-flatten-normal

Answer (score 0):

If you have Excel O365, you could opt for:

Formula in `E1`:

```
=SORT(TRANSPOSE(CHOOSE({1,2},TRANSPOSE(FILTERXML("<t><s>"&TEXTJOIN("</s><s>",,A2:C4&"</s><s>"&A1:C1)&"</s></t>","//s[position() mod 2 = 1]")),TRANSPOSE(FILTERXML("<t><s>"&TEXTJOIN("</s><s>",,A2:C4&"</s><s>"&A1:C1)&"</s></t>","//s[position() mod 2 = 0]")))),1,1)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use Power Query, available in Excel 2010+

It is a part of Excel 2016+ and available as a free Microsoft provided add-in in the earlier versions.

- `Data / Get & Transform / From Table/Range`
- If `A`, `B` and `C` are not the `Headers` then (In the Power Query UI)

  - `Home / Transform / Use First Row as Headers`
- Select all the columns and

  - `Transform / Any Column / Unpivot Columns`
- Sort by `Attribute` and `Value`, in that order
- Move the `Value` column to the first column position
- `Home / Close / Close & Load`

[image]

All of the above steps can be done from the Power Query UI, but here is the generated M-Code

**M-Code**

```
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table3"]}[Content],
    #"Promoted Headers" = Table.PromoteHeaders(Source, [PromoteAllScalars=true]),
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Promoted Headers",{{"A", Int64.Type}, {"B", Int64.Type}, {"C", Int64.Type}}),
    #"Unpivoted Columns" = Table.UnpivotOtherColumns(#"Changed Type", {}, "Attribute", "Value"),
    #"Sorted Rows" = Table.Sort(#"Unpivoted Columns",{{"Attribute", Order.Ascending}, {"Value", Order.Ascending}}),
    #"Reordered Columns" = Table.ReorderColumns(#"Sorted Rows",{"Value", "Attribute"})
in
    #"Reordered Columns"
```